# If $a$ is an arbitrary element of $X$, then what do the balls of radius $1/2$ and $1$ and $2$ around $a$ contain?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> If $X$ is any non-empty set, then the function
>
> $d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
>        0, & x = y \\
>        1, & otherwise.     \end{cases}$
>
> is a metric, known as the discrete metric.
>
> If $a$ is an arbitrary element of $X$, then what do the balls of
>   radius $1/2$ and $1$ and $2$ around $a$ contain?

I have absolutely no idea how to go about answering such a question. I understand what a metric is, I understand what the discrete metric is, and I understand the concept of open balls. However, it is not at all clear to me how one would find what the balls around some arbitrary point $a$ would contain.

In the same section as this problem, I did come across something about finding unique limits and disjoint balls, but that seems to be unrelated to the question at hand? And so, I cannot think of how to proceed with solving this problem.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just interpret literally.  Assuming "ball" means "open ball" here (which is pretty standard) a ball of radius r around a just means everything with a distance less than r from a.  Since any point b other than a has distance 1 from a, the balls of radius 1/2 and of radius 1 are just $\{a\}$ and the ball of radius 2 around a is the entire space $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. We would have $B_{r}(a) = \{ x \in X : d(x, a) < r$, where $r = 1/2, 1, 2$. So, because of the discrete metric distance function, we have that any point other than $a$ has distance $1$ from $a$. Doesn't that mean that any other point in the balls $1/2, 1, 2$ are all classified as having distance $= 1$? Why is $2$ differentiated here?

Comment: Even though $2$ has a radius of $2$, doesn't the definition of the distance function make it so that, regardless, all of the points within it that are not equal to $a$ are classified as having distance equal to $1$? Just as would be the case for $1/2$, despite the fact that the ball only has radius $1/2$?

Comment: Well, yes, but since the points in the balls of radius 1/2 and 1 can't have distance 1 that means there aren't any (except the center).  The balls of radius 1/2 and 1 (and 1/4 and 1/100, etc.) around a are all the same in this case....just $\{a\}$

Comment: Ahh, ok. I thought there was a paradox, but I also thought that the problem was implying that the function definition "overrides" the fact that there aren't any points in the balls $1/2$ and $1$ that have distance $1$ by simply "reclassifying" all points as distance $1$, but I guess that was just me overthinking things. Your explanation was enlightening. So, of course, since the ball of radius $2$ actually *does* have all the points of distance $1$ contained within it, it would be the entire space $X$ -- the set on which we classified our metric space (the discrete metric)!

Comment: Excellent explanation! It allowed me to gain understanding very quickly. Thanks again!